# Add more than one HTML Table data into MySQL DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Good day I have on my form 3 html tables that get populated by users. I am trying to save all the data into MySQL database, but only the data on the third table is getting saved while the other tables data are coming out as null.

Please find below what I had tried so far:

```
<?php
error_reporting(~E_NOTICE); // avoid notice
require_once 'dbconfig.php'; //database connection file
if (isset($_POST['btnsave'])) {
$companyName = $_POST['companyName'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

foreach ($_POST['network'] as $rec => $value){
    foreach ((array) $_POST['network'] as $rec => $value) {
        $network = $_POST['network'][$rec];
        $size = $_POST['size'][$rec];
        $assignedBy = $_POST['assignedby'][$rec];
    }
} 
    foreach ($_POST['network4'] as $rec4 => $value){
    foreach ((array) $_POST['network4'] as $rec4 => $value) {
        $network4 = $_POST['network4'][$rec4];
        $subnetsize = $_POST['subnetsize'][$rec4];
        $max4 = $_POST['max4'][$rec4];
    }
    }    

 foreach ($_POST['network6'] as $key => $value){
    foreach ((array) $_POST['network6'] as $key => $value) {
        $network6 = $_POST['network6'][$key];
        $prefix = $_POST['prefix'][$key];
        $max6 = $_POST['max6'][$key];
    }
 }    

  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO         mytable(companyName,address,network,size,assignedby,network4,subnetsize,max4,net     work6,prefix,max6) '
            . 'VALUES(:compName,     :uaddr,:tblntwk,:tblassignedBy,:tblnetwk4,:tblsubsz4,:tblmx4,:tblnetwk6,:tblprfx      6,:tblmx6)');

    $stmt->bindParam(':compName', $companyName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uaddr', $address);

    //First Table Entries
    $stmt->bindParam(':tblntwk', $network);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tblsze', $size);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tblassignedBy', $assignedBy);

    //Second Table Entries
    $stmt->bindParam(':tblnetwk4', $network4);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tblsubsz4', $subnetsize);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tblmx4', $max4);

    //Third Table Entries: Only this data gets saved
    $stmt->bindParam(':tblnetwk6', $network6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tblprfx6', $prefix);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tblmx6', $max6);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
        //header("refresh:60;index.php"); // redirects image view page
    } else {
        $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
    }
}
?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <title>Table Form</title>
        <SCRIPT language="javascript">
            function addRow(tableID1) {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID1);
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var element1 = document.createElement("input");
                element1.type = "checkbox";
                element1.name = "chkbox[]";
                cell1.appendChild(element1);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='network[]'>";
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='size[]' />";
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='assignedby[]' />";
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID1) {
            try {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID1);
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;

                for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

        function addRow(tableID2) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID2);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.name = "chkbox[]";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='network4[]'>";
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='subnetsize[]' />";
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='max4[]' />";
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID2) {
            try {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID2);
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;

                for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

        function addRow(tableID3) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID3);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.name = "chkbox[]";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='network6[]'>";
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='prefix[]' />";
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='max6[]' />";
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID3) {
            try {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID3);
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;

                for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </SCRIPT>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

            </head>
            <body>
                <?php
                if (isset($errMSG)) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <strong><?php echo $errMSG; ?></strong>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                } else if (isset($successMSG)) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $successMSG; ?></strong>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>  
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal"> 

                    <h>Customer Information</h></p>

                    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                        <tr>
                            <td><label class="control-label">Company/Client Name:.</label></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="companyName" placeholder="Company/Client Name" value="<?php echo $companyName; ?>" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label class="control-label">Address.</label></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>" /></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>

                        <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('ipv4addressspacetable')" />
                        <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onClick="deleteRow('ipv4addressspacetable')" />
                        <form action="" method="post" name="f">  
                            <TABLE id="firsttable" width="425" border="1">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th width="98"></th>
                                        <th width="94">Network</th>
                                        <th width="121">Size</th>
                                        <th width="84">Assigned By</th>
                                        <th width="121">Assigned Date</th>
                                        <th width="84">Percentage in Use</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="ipv4addressspacetable">
                                </tbody>
                            </TABLE>


                    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('ipv4addressspaceusage')" />
                    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onClick="deleteRow('ipv4addressspaceusage')" />
                    <form action="" method="post" name="f">  
                        <TABLE width="425" border="1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="98"></th>
                                    <th width="94">Network</th>
                                    <th width="121">Subnet Size</th>
                                    <th width="84">(Hosts) Max</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="ipv4addressspaceusage">
                            </tbody>
                        </TABLE>

                        <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('ipv6addressspaceusage')" />
                        <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onClick="deleteRow('ipv6addressspaceusage')" />
                        <form action="" method="post" name="f">  
                            <TABLE width="425" border="1">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th width="98"></th>
                                        <th width="94">Network</th>
                                        <th width="121">Prefix</th>
                                        <th width="84">Max</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="ipv6addressspaceusage">
                                </tbody>
                            </TABLE>
                        <button type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; save</button>

                        </form>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
                        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                        </body>
                        </html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `:tblprfx      6,` you realize that that is a syntax error right there, with the spaces and for `net     work6`.

Comment: `error_reporting(~E_NOTICE); // avoid notice` should removed while developing ;)

Comment: And why do you do each `foreach` twice ???

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Please kindly ignore syntax errors as they occurred while I was posting the code on the forum. The double foreach is an error that I overlooked please ignore it.